# How do i fix my random planet name generator?

Tags: c#, wpf, random

I am making a simple space exploration game with C# and WPF. I have a bug that continues to persist despite my best efforts to fix it. I have a star class where its constructor will randomly generate a amount of planets with unique names via the Random class. The issue is that duplicate names will appear in the combo box despite removing the used name from the list that contains them.

The constructor:

```
public Star(List<Planet> _planetlist)
{
    int range = _planetlist.Count;
    int amountOfPlanets = random.Next(1, 6);
    List<String> usableNames = new List<String>(PlanetNames);

    for (int i = 0; i != amountOfPlanets; i++)
    {
        Planet planet = _planetlist[random.Next(0, range)];
        planet.name = usableNames[random.Next(0, usableNames.Count)];
        usableNames.Remove(planet.name);
        systemPlanets.Add(planet);
    }
}
```

The outcome:
[Duplicate names occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlRkx.png)

This wont occur every time you run the program due to the nature of randomness, but demonstrates the code isn't working.

I have tried various approaches to try to fix the bug. The solution shown is old and didn't work:

```
public Star(List<Planet> _planetlist)
{
    int range = _planetlist.Count - 1; // range stores the amount of planets within the passed planetList parameter
    int totalPlanets = random.Next(1, 6); // The amount of planets within the system can range from 1 -> 6
    int planetPointer; // Not initalized yet, but will store a random number from 0 to the length of the passed planet list. This is used to select a random planet from the planetlist among other uses.
    int iteration = 0;

    while (iteration < totalPlanets)
    {
        planetPointer = random.Next(0, range);
        Planet planet = _planetlist[planetPointer]; // Random planet from the planet list is selected and passed to the Planet varible.
        planet.Name = planet.PlanetNames[planetPointer]; // Random name is selected for the planet.
        systemplanets.Add(planet);

        for (int iterator = 0; iterator <= totalPlanets; iterator++) // This for loop is used to find if the current planets name is identical to other planets in the system.
        {
            if (planetlist.Count == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (systemplanets[iterator].Name == planet.Name)
            {
                planet.Name = planet.PlanetNames[random.Next(0, planet.PlanetNames.Count)];
                iterator = 0;
            }
        }
        iteration++;
    }
}
```

Here is that part of the code that populates the combobox with each planets name:

```
private void buttonTravel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String uniAgeString = LabelUniAge.Content.ToString();
    ComboBoxStar.Items.Clear();
    ComboBoxPlanet.Items.Clear();

    if (ulong.TryParse(uniAgeString, out ulong convertedAge) == true)
    {
        universe.ageUniverse(convertedAge);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    LabelUniAge.Content = universe.universeage;

    Star star = new Star(planetList);

    foreach (Planet planet in star.SystemPlanets)
    {
        ComboBoxPlanet.Items.Add(planet.name);
    }
}
```

If you need access to the whole project you can find it here: https://github.com/David-s2005/SpaceGame

A explanation to why this doesn't work would be much appreciated! Thank you for your time.

**EDIT: Found a solution?**

Hello everyone reading my question, i have fixed my problems through the means of black magic and bashing my head against the wall.

I have been tracing the process my code goes though using breakpoints and saw that everything seemed to work fine. I wrote what randomly generated names were created and wrote them down. Every time i did this all names were unique as my conditional statements were working fine and filtering out duplicates. I've since lost this code but it was vaguely similar to my first solution with given advice kept in mind (Thank you BTW!). The strange part was when i tracked the part of the code that added the generated names to the combo box sometimes a name would change to a existing name!

Instead of fixing my already existing code i essentially re-wrote my entire process of giving each planet a unique name by making a list with unique names that the combo box uses (also gives each planets name attribute a unique name, wow!). The way i've implemented the solution is shown here:

Planet Class:
'''
public void generatePlanetNames(int _totalPlanets)
{
usedNames.Clear();
string generatedName;
bool isUnique;

```
    for (int i = 0; i != _totalPlanets; i++)
    {
        isUnique = false;

        while (isUnique == false)
        {
            generatedName = planetNames[random.Next(1, planetNames.Count)];
            if (usedNames.Contains(generatedName))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                isUnique = true;
                name = generatedName;
                usedNames.Add(generatedName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

'''

The relevent part of the button click event:
'''

```
Star star = new Star(planetList);
int totalSystemPlanets = random.Next(1, 7);
HotParadise.generatePlanetNames(totalSystemPlanets);

foreach (string planetName in HotParadise.usedNames) 
{
    ComboBoxPlanet.Items.Add(planetName);
}
```

'''

**TLDR:** No idea what was causing the issue as values being added to the combo box would seemingly change at random! Created a new method for the class that fixed the problem. Maybe someone smarter than me can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

`Planet planet = _planetlist[random.Next(0, range)];` might return the *same* planet object multiple times, if you happen to get the same random number.

Then the last `planet.Name = ...` on a planet object will overwrite the names previously set.